# D3 and topojson Nan error due to scaling and transformation

Tags: d3.js, gis, topojson, wgs84

My code:

```
//http://www.mapshaper.org/
//http://ogre.adc4gis.com/
var height = 600;
var width = 900;
var projection = d3.geo.mercator();
var cluster = void 0;
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
var svg = d3.select("#map")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
var states;

d3.json('https://api.myjson.com/bins/374pl1', function (data) {
    //console.log('city', data);
    //console.log('city', data.objects.collection);
    //console.log(data);
    //console.log(data);
    states = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.new);
    //console.log(states);
    // Setup the scale and translate
    projection.scale(1).translate([0, 0]);
    var b = path.bounds(states);
    //console.log(b);
    var t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s *
                (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];
    var s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] -
            b[0][1]) / height);
    projection.scale(s).translate(t);
    var map = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'boundary');
    mexico= map.selectAll('path').data(states.features);
    mexico.enter().append('path').attr('d', path);

    //console.log(clusterNameSiteCountJson);
});
```

**I am getting error :**

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZ"
```

I could not create fiddle due to access-origin policy.
http://jsfiddle.net/338bowdr/3/

I don't get any error if I scale to 9000 and use coordinates.

```
 projection.scale(9000)
                .center([83, 29.5]);
```

states.feature:

[image]

Comment: What does `states.features` look like? Is it in the format that's required by your `path` function?

Comment: @adilapapaya I have added states.features

Comment: Is this the format that's required by the `d3.geo.path().projection(projection)` function? In a nutshell, the error you're getting is because the `path` function doesn't know how to deal with the `states.features` data you're passing into it so make sure it's in the necessary format.

Comment: @adilapapaya I am trying to use mercator. My actual projection is EPGS 4326 i.e. WGS 84.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience MapShaper does not export a json that topojson can use. I have exported a topojson file from a shape file of Mexico states and put it in a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnLoq1Lw/2/) for you. You can download the Nepal topojson [here](https://bindust.com/files/nepaltopo.json). Please do not link to that file in your project, I only put it there because it was too big for myjson.com.

Your example code seems overly complex when it's very simple to draw this map with just this code. Unless I'm missing something.

```
var width = 1000,
  height = 1000;

var scale = d3.scale.quantize();
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height',height);

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .scale(3000)
  .center([83.96, 28.27]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
  .projection(projection);

d3.json('https://bindust.com/files/nepaltopo.json', function(data) {
  svg.append('g').attr('class','states')
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.nepal).features)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', path);
})
```

Comment: I think something is wrong with my data set I changed the source of data then it does not work https://jsfiddle.net/bnLoq1Lw/1/

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you on that. But you have a working Mexico map now that you can work with and mix in you own data too. I have the id on the path as the Mexico fips.

Comment: I got the error due to scaling and transformation. I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: The topojson file you are trying to use does not look valid to me. Why not just use the working example I provided?

Comment: because I am not using mexico :( !

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to show nepal and provided a link to a working topojson. Your code lead me to believe it was mexico. Hope this helps :)